# Why am I getting the error "application-defined or object defined error"?

Tags: excel, vba

Where is the error `application-defined or object defined error` coming from? It seems to be coming from the formula that I created. Please help. It really should not be this hard to write code in VBA but for some reason it is not working.

```
Sub get_levels()

    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim ticker As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastRowC As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim current_input_position As Long
    Dim sheet As String
    Dim mula As String
    Dim updatedTicker As String

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Count = 0
    sheet = "Test_Sheet"

    current_input_position = 2

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Label:

    Set rng = Range("A" & current_input_position & ":A" & lastRow)
    For Each ticker In rng.Cells

        lastRowC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
        updatedTicker = ticker & " A" & " Mtge"

        MsgBox updatedTicker 

        mula = "GCBDC 2018-1A A Mtge"

        Range("E2").formula = "=BDS(" & mula & ",""MTGE_CMO_GROUP_LIST"",""Headers=N"")"

    Next ticker


End Sub
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Have you added a Tools / Reference for Bloomberg?  =BDS is not a formula that is native to Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Bloomberg Add-In is functional (try calling `BDS` manually from a regular worksheet to check), I think you may need to change this line:

`Range("E2").formula = "=BDS(" & mula & ",""MTGE_CMO_GROUP_LIST"",""Headers=N"")"`

to

`Range("E2").Formula = "=BDS(""" & mula & """,""MTGE_CMO_GROUP_LIST"",""Headers=N"")"`

If your variable `mula` has spaces in it (and even if it doesn't), it might need to have `"` on either side.

(Also, most of your `Range` and `Cells` references have no worksheet or workbook specified -- meaning they'll refer to whatever workbook and worksheet happens to be active whilst the code is running. Broadly speaking, you don't want this, but that wasn't your question.)

Comment: Genius. Thanks, really helped me out here.